# what is the procedure to get linkedIn API for linkedin integration in our website

Tags: linkedin-api

We have our mini CRM website. We want to add linkedin functionality to send targeted campaigns to our linkedin contacts from our website. So Please let us know what is the process to get and integrate the API in our website.

Is this API open source?

we are using C#, MVC 1.0 and MSSQL server database.

Answer (score 2):

Bulk messaging is not supported by the LinkedIn APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Means like bulk emails(email campaigns), we cannot send bulk linkedin message at a time through our website after integration.

Comment: we want to do target messaging campaigns by using linkedIn through our website